# Crank-Nickolson

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have these two equation
$$
\frac{\partial q(t,x)}{\partial t} = 
\frac{\partial^2 q(t,x)}{\partial x^2} 
- \frac{L_1 a(t, x) q(t, x)}{1 + \frac{L_2}{L} (1 - q(t,x))}\\
\frac{\partial a(t,x)}{\partial t} = 
\frac{\partial^2 a(t,x)}{\partial x^2} 
- \frac{L_1 a(t, x) q(t, x)}{1 + \frac{L_2}{L} (1 - q(t,x))}\\
$$
with boundary condition 
$$
q\big|_{t=0} = 0, \quad
a\big|_{t=0} = y, \quad
q\big|_{t>=0, x-> infinity} = 0, \quad
a\big|_{t>=0, x-> infinity} = y, \quad
da/dx\big|_{x=0} = 0, \quad
q\big|_{x=0} = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(f - g t)}, 
$$
and $f,g,L_1,L_2,L$ are all constants.

I need to know what is $\frac{\partial q(t,x)}{\partial x}$ at $x=0$.

I think I need to use Crank-Nickolson but don't know how. The info on the website wasn't enough. :(

I'd really appreciate if you help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please learn to use formatting

Comment: sorry but I'm not a professional user; I hopefully eventually write in better format in near future with more practice but for now I'd appreciate if you ignore it and if u can plz help me with the answer. thanks

Comment: You don't need $q_x$ and $a_x$ at $x = 0$, what you need is $q$ and $a$ (or $q_x$ and $a_x$) at $x = 1$ (assuming the domain is $[0, 1]$), i.e. the right boundary condition. That will make the problem correctly posed. Also your IC and BC are inconsistent, is it intended?